# "Cannot find module '@reactflow/core' or its corresponding type declarations."

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, types

I forked reactflow, i want to make some changes but even though i didnt make changes i cant use it. It gives type error

[image]

I tried to use "pnpm i @types/reactflow" but it didnt work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [README](https://github.com/wbkd/react-flow) file of React Flow you have to follow these steps:

> Before you can start developing please make sure that you have [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/) installed (`npm i -g pnpm`). Then install the dependencies using pnpm: `pnpm install`.

> Run `pnpm build` once and then you can use `pnpm dev` for local development.